Do wreaths have special significance in seals?
I'm currently working on designing a personal wax seal for use on correspondence and when wrapping gifts. I am basing it primarily upon the heraldry of one side of my family (which, if it helps, is Courish/East Prussian).
As it stands, I am adding in a wreath to fill empty space around the edge of the seal. However, before I commit this design to a seal matrix, I would like to check — do wreaths have any special significance in Prussian iconography (or German or Western generally) that I should be aware of?

Depends on the plant. Oak leaf wreaths are commonly used to give German (military) orders a higher rank. For laurel, I am not aware of any significance beside the one known since antiquity, a gift for a winner.

I don't see an objectively answerable history question here. You may want to read  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurel_wreath and https://www.reddit.com/r/heraldry/comments/t61bsu/do_the_use_of_wreaths_have_any_symbolic/

OT slightly but there was a dispute when the memorials to the fallen in the Great War (WWI) were being built in the 1920s.  The argument was whether the wreaths should be laurel for victory or olive for peace.

Depends on what you would call "special". Oak leaves, or oak in general, is not reserved in heraldry and actually quite common, so it's not "stealing valor" in and of itself if that is what you are worried about (unless the overall design of your seal conspires in that direction). The statement is one of strength and fortitude, especially in conflict, and victory.
